# Create a user interface to request privileges and references in Snowflake Native Apps

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I'm creating a Snowflake app using Native Apps Framework. I want to access to consumer tables, so I need to create a user interface to request privileges and references, as explained in this page of Snowflake documentation: [text](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/native-apps/requesting-ui)

Before adding the following code, I  added the enviroment.yml file in the same directory as main Streamlit file and I also added the snowflake-native-apps-permission package as a dependency there.

In section "Importing the Permissions Python SDK in Your Streamlit App",  explains that in order to import the permissions into my streamlit app, I have to include this statement in my app:

`import snowflake.permissions as permissions;`

But, when I launch the app, the error shown in the picture appears.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75PWl.png)

Anyone knows how to fix it?

(I inserted the statement in the hello_snowflake.py file which is the one I use to write the streamlit code.)

(After implementing the steps above, I also defined the reference in the manifest file as explained in the Snowflake documentation)

Thanks for your help!!